# Blinking screen while using wireless connection

Tags: wireless, laptop, screen, atheros

I've bought Dell Inspiron 5548 laptop and faced up with the next problem - when I'm using a build-in wireless card screen starts blinking, it happens every time when I'm using it(watch online video, download file, etc). And it only happens with a built-in wireless card, Ethernet and USB dongle work without issues.

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 4c:bb:58:6e:6e:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-59-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:d2100000-d217ffff memory:d2180000-d218ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type o problem in my MacBook 13' early 2015.

I was able to stop the blinking by changing the wi-fi channel, in my case to 2.412 GHz (Channel 1).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already using this frequency and my router don't support 5 GHz frequency.

Comment: Have you tried to change to another 2.4 GHz channel?